# faking API calls /w NSubstitute, for unit testing

Tags: c#, unit-testing, nunit, nsubstitute

I got a lot of function calls like the one below that I want to unit test but are unsure of how i should approach functions like these..
Do I just test it with the real URL and API calls?? but then it won't be a real unit test since I including things which I don't have control of... which leads me to the conclusion that I have to mock the `RestClient` out?? where I need to make a `RestClient Foo(ApiUrl + ApiDirectory);` which I can use `NSubtitute` on, is it the right way??

Would you guys approach it the same way? or is there a smart way do this unit test?

```
// ReSharper disable once InconsistentNaming
public IRestResponse TCAPIconnection( Method b, long c = 0, object d = null)
{
    var client = c == 0 ? new RestClient(ApiUrl + ApiDirectory) : new RestClient(ApiUrl + ApiDirectory + c);
    var request = new RestRequest(b);
    request.AddHeader("Authorization", Token);
    if (d != null)
    {
        request.AddJsonBody(d);
    }
    var response = client.Execute(request);
    return response;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your provided approach is not going to fly on a greater in size system as well as you actually alter your original code for testing purposes.

Mocking frameworks are generally used for unit-testing. Unit test in itself is just a small fraction of functionality, a single method. It most definitely do not involve services.

What you should be going for is abstractions upon which you can simply mock an `interface` which your services use.

Lets consider a short example. You have a `IBluetoothService` which is being injected into `BluetoothManager` class. The interface would expose few methods which on the test mode will be mocked.

```
public interface IBluetoothService
{
    object GetData();
    bool SendData(object request);
}

public class BluetoothAPI : IBluetoothService
{
    public object GetData()
    {
        // API logic to get data.
        return new object();
    }

    public bool SendData(object request)
    {
        // API logic to send data.
        return false;
    }
}
```

In your `Logger` class `constructor` you should inject `IBluetoothService`.

```
public class Logger
{
    private readonly IBluetoothService _bluetoothService;
    public Logger(IBluetoothService bluetoothService)
    {
        _bluetoothService = bluetoothService;
    }

    public void LogData(string textToLog)
    {
        if (!_bluetoothService.SendData(textToLog))
            throw new ArgumentException("Could not log data");
    }
}
```

So since you got this abstraction level going in your application you effectively start testing it.

```
public void SmokeTest()
{
    var substitute = Substitute.For<IBluetoothService>();
    substitute.GetData().Returns(1);
    // Swap true with false and test will fail.
    substitute.SendData(Arg.Any<object>()).Returns(true);
    var sut = new Logger(substitute);
    try
    {
        sut.LogData("Some data to log");
    }
    catch (ArgumentException ex)
    {
        Assert.Fail("Mocked API call returned wrong value.");
    }
}
```

`NSubstitute` is a powerful tool which allows you to test everything if you have the correct architecture in you application. To achieve a testable code you need little to nothing, just inject `interface`. This does not only allow you to have a testable but also more maintainable approach in software development.