# Can I handle case insensitive string in my mock?

Tags: c#, unit-testing, testing, justmock

NUnit 3.4.1, JustMock 2016.2.713.2

I have the class under test:

```
public class AppManager {
    public string[] GetAppSets() => Registry.LocalMachine
        .OpenSubKey(@"SOFTWARE\Autodesk\AutoCAD", false)
        ?.GetSubKeyNames();
}
```

Also, I have the test for `GetAppSets` method:

```
[Test]
public void GetAppSets_Returns_ValidValue() {

    const string subkey = @"SOFTWARE\Autodesk\AutoCAD";
    /* The sets of applications which are based on 
     * AutoCAD 2009-2017. */
    string[] fakeSets = new[] { "R17.2", "R18.0",
        "R18.1", "R18.2", "R19.0", "R19.1", "R20.0",
        "R20.1","R21.0" };

    RegistryKey rk = Mock.Create<RegistryKey>();

    Mock.Arrange(() => rk.GetSubKeyNames()).Returns(
        fakeSets);

    Mock.Arrange(() => Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey
    (subkey, false)).Returns(rk);

    AppManager appMng = new AppManager();
    string[] appSets = appMng.GetAppSets();

    Assert.AreEqual(fakeSets, appSets);
}
```

It works. But my test will be failure if `GetAppSets` method uses "*Software\Autodesk\AutoCAD*" or "*software\autodesk\autocad*" string instead of "S*OFTWARE\Autodesk\AutoCAD*": the `appSets` variable will be `null` if string case will be changed (because that registry key doesn't exist on my computer).

So, at this case *either* tester needs to know the`GetAppSets` method implementation (the bad variant), *or* to handle parameter like the *case insensitive* string.

Is it possible to use the second variant?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that the answer by @Karolis misses the point of the question.

The correct solution is to use a matcher in the arrangement to match the key in a case-insensitive manner:

```
    var mock = Mock.Create<RegistryKey>();
    Mock.Arrange(() => Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey(
        Arg.Matches<string>(s => StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase.Equals(s, @"SOFTWARE\Autodesk\AutoCAD")),
        Arg.AnyBool)
    ).Returns(mock);


    var mockKey = Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey(@"software\autodesk\autocad", false);
```

In the above `mockKey` will be the same instance as `mock`, because of the argument matcher on the first argument.

Answer (score 1):

**Answer to original question:**

You can use an overloaded version of equality assertion.

```
Assert.AreEqual(fakeSets, appSets, true);
```

Signature:

```
public static void AreEqual(
string expected,
string actual,
bool ignoreCase)
```

Source: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms243448.aspx

**Answer to updated question:**

```
for(int i = 0; i < appSets.Length, i++)
{   // If there is mismatch in length Exception will fail the test.
    Assert.AreEqual(fakeSets[i], appSets[i], true);
}
```

Comment: No, my problem is other. The `appSets` will be `null` if string case will be changed (because that registry key doesn't exist on my computer). I added this addition info into my topic right now.

Comment: I see your point. It is a unit-test as stated in your tags, thus interaction with other components such as registry is permitted. Use a mock for GetAppSets as well.

Comment: I use a mock for my `GetAppSets` in my test. I use NUnit and JustMock frameworks.

Comment: @AndreyBushman You cannot mock concrete implementations. Take a look http://stackoverflow.com/a/37194417/5505949

Comment: Thank you. Also I have the remark to your answer (about third parameter): I compare two string arrays instead of two strings in my test.

Comment: For comparring two strings NUnit has also such method: `StringAssert.AreEqualIgnoringCase("string1", "string2");`, but I need to compare two string arrays.